# How to unit test method with if else and no return conditions

Tags: unit-testing

I have a method with following code:

```
public void myMethod() {
    if (condition1) {
        doSomething1();
        if (condition2) {
            doSomething2();
        } else {
            doSomething3();
        }
    }
 }
```

Now doSomething1, doSomething2, doSomething3 are void methods.
How to unit-test myMethod ?
eg: if condition1 is satisfied check if doSomething1 was called.

Is there something we can do to refactor this to make easily testable ?

Answer (score 1):

A general approach could be 3 test cases.  Each test case would exercise a single condition.  For each test case:

- doSomethingX would be patched with a test object, (there are mock libraries for pretty much all languages)
- conditionX would be triggered
- doSomethingX would execute
- test would assert that doSomethingX was actually called

---

There are many strategies for removing the need to mock.

if `doSomethingX` is an instance method then you could create a [test specific subclass](http://xunitpatterns.com/Test-Specific%20Subclass.html) and override `doSomethingX` and make your assertion in the subclass.

You could also refactor your method to require the caller to inject the `doSomethingX` dependency (dependency injection)

`public void myMethod(somethingStrategy)`

Then the test could easily configure a mock object and call `myMethod` with the mock object.

Dependency injection could take place on the class level by having the [class be instantiated](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance) with a `somethingStrategy` as well.

Answer (score 0):

(a) The fact that these methods return void means their outcome is irrelevant, we just don't care. But you need to test the outcome, and need therefore to know the outcome. So this is a huge red flag that the code isn't SOLID and needs refactoring.

(b) Hey, this could be legacy code that is impossible to change, so if your methods truly are voids, then the following refactoring could help, if you then assert that the myNewMethod2 and doSomething2/3 are called once / not called at all depedndant upon the conditions (e.g. via MOQ unit testing framework)

```
    public myNewMethod()
    {
        bool cnd1 = (condition1);
        bool cnd2 = (condition2);
        if(cnd1)
        {
            myNewMethod2(cnd2);
        }
    }

    public myNewMethod2(bool cnd2)
    {
        doSomething1();
        myNewMthod3(cnd2);
    }

    public myNewMethod3(bool cnd2)
    {
        if (cnd2) 
        {
            doSomething2();
        } 
        else 
        {
            doSomething3();
        }   
    }
```

(c) Another strategy for voids, which I'm not a great fan of, but leaves your original code largely intact, is this:

```
    public void myMethod() {
        try
        {
            if (condition1) {
            doSomething1();
            if (condition2) {
                doSomething2();
            } else {
                doSomething3();
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            //  
        }
     }
```

Your unit test can then assert that no exception is thrown. Not ideal, but if needs must...